# Allow a margin of difference of

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

I'm not sure if I use the word "margin" correctly.

I've two different scenarios:

1. To describe the measurement given may not be accurate because it is measured manually.
2. To describe there may be differences in the actual measurement of the product because they are handmade.

The sentences I have in mind are:

1. Please allow **a margin of difference of 1-2cm** as they are manually measured.
2. Please allow **1-2cm margin of error** as they are manually measured.
3. Please allow **a margin of 1-2cm difference** as they are manually measured.

Are the above sentences acceptable?

Comment: "margin of error" is a fixed expression - it means "a tolerance".  "Margin of difference" is not an expression used in English.  It might be understood, but I wouldn't use it if I were you. It's odd.

Comment: Thanks @BillyKerr If *margin of error* is a fixed expression, will it be understood if one says *please allow a margin of 1-2cm* without the use of the word *error*?

Comment: I'm not sure. A margin is a space/gap at the edge of a document.  Is that what you want to say?

Comment: Thanks @BillyKerr That's not what I want to say and what you said has answered my question. Ha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we wish to give a measurement, and also at the same time to allow some amount of variation, we often use the word 'tolerance'. If I am making rods nominally 1 metre long, and the lengths may be between 99 cm and 101 cm, I could say 'Please allow a tolerance of plus or minus 1 cm'.

> tolerance noun
> (VARIATION)
> ENGINEERING, MATHEMATICS
>
> the amount by which a measurement or calculation might
> change and still be acceptable:
>
> *parts that are made to tolerances of a thousandth of an inch*

[Tolerance (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tolerance)

Comment: Thanks! If I may further ask, can the word "tolerance" be used generally for any types of items/scenarios in a similar context? For e.g. tables, clothes/bags, height of building, distance between two objects and to describe color variation?

Comment: I'm sorry, if I may ask another, Is it redundant to use the word *difference* if *tolerance* is used?  For example, `Please allow a tolerance of 1-2cm difference.`

Comment: @OrganicHeart - Yes. "difference" is redundant. The word tolerance already implies that there will be changes/differences. No need to repeat it.